# Password protect a folder

Tags: encryption, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zip

I have several files in a folder. I want to encrypt that folder. What's the way I could do it? I tried the following:

Used the command zip with encrypt option. This does encrypt the files. But the files are viewable inside the zip folder. Only when you click on the individual file does it ask for the password.

Is there a way to set passwords at the folder level?  I am using this command:

```
zip --encrypt form.zip folder
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS as WSL on windows 11.

Comment: You can use Cryptkeeper for the encryption.

Comment: @guiverc I am using WSL. May be that is the reason? Or probably I need to update it

Answer (score 2):

1. Install gpg

   ```
   sudo apt install -y gnupg
   ```
2. tar the directory and encrypt it with gpg...

   ```
   tar czvf - folder | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 -o form.tar.gz.gpg
   ```

   you'll be prompted to set a passphrase
3. If you want to extract files from the encrypted tar then you'd run

   ```
   gpg -d form.tar.gz.gpg | tar xzvf -
   ```

   you'll be prompted to enter that same passphrase you entered in step 2 before the files can be extracted

Answer (score 0):

gpg can also be used to encrypt single files from the directory your in with

`gpg -c filename`

-c requires a passphrase and encrypts with AES128 Symmetric Cipher, then use

`gpg filename.gpg`

with the password you set to extract it to the working directory.

To know which encryption you have to use just type `gpg --version`

Frankly, I think the easiest way forward if multiple people have access to your login, which to be honest they shouldn't, is to create an account on your PC only you have access to and create passworded network shares to the individual folders you want to share, but be secure.