# Seamless encryption of a partition

Tags: encryption

I'm sorry that I don't have the time to research and try solutions myself which I would normally do.

My PC is going to be used by other people and I have only some private files that I want to protect.
I am envisioning the following: I would like to encrypt a partition where my private files are with my Ubuntu login password. While I'm logged in the partition should be automatically unencrypted so that it is usable whithout me typing the password again.

I'm thankful for suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Used by other people"? How? If they don't have `sudo` access, standard Unix/Linux permissions and ACLs (Access Control Lists) should be enough. If they do have `sudo` (`root` access) you're hosed anyhow.

Comment: Alternative to encrypt a directory (not a partition): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437603/password-protect-a-folder